# Version History and Audit log don't match

Tags: sharepoint-online, version-history, audit-log-reports

Reviewing the audit log under Event Data it says

```
<Version><Major>0</Major><Minor>7</Minor></Version>
```

for "Greg". But when I actually look at the document's version history, I see version 0.7 with someone entirely different.

Is there a reason these don't match up?

Is it a case of someone editing the file and then deleting that file version and SharePoint reusing that version number?

For instance in the Version History I see

0.8 Bob

0.7 Rebecca

0.6 Mark

Given the audit log, I would expect to see 0.7 as Greg but I am seeing Rebecca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are same.

Major versions are identified by whole numbers, such as `1.0`; minor versions are identified by decimal numbers, such as `0.1`.

The "`<Version><Major>0</Major><Minor>7</Minor></Version>`" means the major is 0 and minor is 7, so the version number is `0.7`.

In the library, we can control which users can view the minor versions (drafts).

[image]

In many organizations, draft security is set to allow only the owner of a file and people who have permissions to approve files. That means that minor versions cannot be seen by anyone else until a major version is published.

By the way, site collection admins has full control of the site. They can see the minor versions.

Information about [major and minor versions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-does-versioning-work-in-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-0f6cd105-974f-44a4-aadb-43ac5bdfd247?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fIntroduction-to-versioning-49e87cfa-1f18-427b-852b-7ff1612ef672&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: My question that the log shows version 0.7 as one person, but the version history shows a different person for the same exact version. I am not sure which one is correct.

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: I am the site collection admin and I can see minor versions.  I don't see how minor version visibility explains why I am seeing the same version of the document in both the audit log and the version history, but with different authors. I'll update my question to be cleaer

Comment: As you are using SPO, get audit log reports in the Office 365 Security & Compliance Center https://protection.office.com/#/unifiedauditlog instead. Check the version of the file, see if you can get right version.

Comment: Thanks, that log was much more comprehensive and was exactly what I was looking for.